# Почему при загрузке страницы мелькает всплывающее окно?

Tags: javascript, html, css

При загрузке страницы да несколько секунд появляется и исчезает всплывающее окно? В связи с чем оно появляется?

http://ilyin1ib.beget.tech/

Весь код jsfiddle.net/8rwh5nvk/1/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А должно быть как?

Comment: пока грузятся js скрипты попап видны, сделайте свойства для попапов в css файле visibility: hidden к примеру или display: none

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Там вне всех функций есть строчка

```
$('.popup').fadeOut();
```

вот она и закрывает окно